# How do I ignore white space, tabs, new lines, when getting with an input string?

Tags: python-3.x

```
print ('enter the text you would like searched')
myString = input()

# something
# like 
# this

print(myString)
```

Only the first line is printed. I've tried a lot of different things but I #decided to just post this for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about reading multiple lines of input.

The simplest approach would be to [accept all text until EOF](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines):

```
import sys
my_lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
print(' - '.join(my_lines))
```

Mac / linux users would type CTRL-D to signal end-of-file. On windows use CTRL-Z.

Alternatively you might loop through an `input()` statement until recognizing special text, such as `'END'`.

As a separate matter, to strip or replace [whitespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) from a string, use something like this:

```
print('_'.join(my_string.split()))
```

Comment: how do I insert that into my existing code? I'm very new to python, this started as a program to teach me how to count characters in a string but i decided i wanted it do something more interesting.